# How to change the 'src' value of a few <img> tags using the 'for loop'?

Tags: javascript, html

Each 'dice' is supposed to display a random picture from an `array` of pictures.
How to change the value of the `src` attribute of each `<img>` tag using the `for loop`?

I was trying to use the for loop but it doesn't work...

Thank you for your tips and help.

```
 const dice1 = document.getElementById('dice1');
 const dice2 = document.getElementById('dice2');
 const dice3 = document.getElementById('dice3');
 const dice4 = document.getElementById('dice4');
 const dice5 = document.getElementById('dice5');
 const dice6 = document.getElementById('dice6');
 const button = document.getElementById('button');

const imgs = [dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5, dice6];

let pics = ['https://i.postimg.cc/MfVDpSmQ/Eagle.jpg', 
'https://i.postimg.cc/QKGQPzZx/Man.jpg', 
'https://i.postimg.cc/1g7MWMzf/Dog.jpg', 
'https://i.postimg.cc/xc9HzM07/Telephone.jpg', 
'https://i.postimg.cc/4mwcbyy3/Robot.jpg', 
'https://i.postimg.cc/ctRRNcd7/Moon.jpg', 
'https://i.postimg.cc/xJW5QCMQ/Dinosaur.jpg',
'https://i.postimg.cc/hhdMrLRt/Fish.jpg', 
'https://i.postimg.cc/Ty1JWmcG/Flowers.jpg'];


const display = (arr) => {
    for (let i = 0; i > arr.length; i++){
       return i.src = pics[Math.floor(Math.random() * pics.length)]
    }
 }

button.onclick = display(imgs)
```

Comment: Your current logic implies that duplicate pictures are OK - is that desirable, or do you want to make sure pictures *aren't* repeated?

Comment: @CertainPerformance, it is not desirable actually, I am figuring now how to do that, the if statement will do, right? But no idea how to start with that issue.

Comment: See edit to my answer, just use `splice` on a copy of the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a number of issues in your code:

> `button.onclick = display(imgs)`

`button.onclick` should be set to the function itself, and not the value of it when it runs on a given value. What you could do is use [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) instead.

> `for (let i = 0; i > arr.length; i++){`

`i` starts at `0`, which means it will always be lower than `arr.length`, and so this loop will never run.

> `i.src = ...`

`i` is a variable that contains a number, not the image with index `i`. You probably want to use `imgs[i]` here instead, which references image no. `i`.

---

This is one way to apply the fixes I've proposed above:

```js
const dice1 = document.getElementById('dice1');
const dice2 = document.getElementById('dice2');
const dice3 = document.getElementById('dice3');
const dice4 = document.getElementById('dice4');
const dice5 = document.getElementById('dice5');
const dice6 = document.getElementById('dice6');
const button = document.getElementById('button');

const imgs = [dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5, dice6];

let pics = ['https://i.postimg.cc/MfVDpSmQ/Eagle.jpg', 
    'https://i.postimg.cc/QKGQPzZx/Man.jpg', 
    'https://i.postimg.cc/1g7MWMzf/Dog.jpg', 
    'https://i.postimg.cc/xc9HzM07/Telephone.jpg', 
    'https://i.postimg.cc/4mwcbyy3/Robot.jpg', 
    'https://i.postimg.cc/ctRRNcd7/Moon.jpg', 
    'https://i.postimg.cc/xJW5QCMQ/Dinosaur.jpg',
    'https://i.postimg.cc/hhdMrLRt/Fish.jpg', 
    'https://i.postimg.cc/Ty1JWmcG/Flowers.jpg'];


const display = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        imgs[i].src = pics[Math.floor(Math.random() * pics.length)]
    }
};

button.onclick = display;
```

```html
<button id="button">Roll the dice</button>
<img id="dice1"/>
<img id="dice2"/>
<img id="dice3"/>
<img id="dice4"/>
<img id="dice5"/>
<img id="dice6"/>
```

---

Edit: To avoid repeating the same image, use [`.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) after calculating the random index of the picture (as @CertainPerformance suggested):

```js
const dice1 = document.getElementById('dice1');
const dice2 = document.getElementById('dice2');
const dice3 = document.getElementById('dice3');
const dice4 = document.getElementById('dice4');
const dice5 = document.getElementById('dice5');
const dice6 = document.getElementById('dice6');
const button = document.getElementById('button');

const imgs = [dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5, dice6];

let pics = ['https://i.postimg.cc/MfVDpSmQ/Eagle.jpg', 
    'https://i.postimg.cc/QKGQPzZx/Man.jpg', 
    'https://i.postimg.cc/1g7MWMzf/Dog.jpg', 
    'https://i.postimg.cc/xc9HzM07/Telephone.jpg', 
    'https://i.postimg.cc/4mwcbyy3/Robot.jpg', 
    'https://i.postimg.cc/ctRRNcd7/Moon.jpg', 
    'https://i.postimg.cc/xJW5QCMQ/Dinosaur.jpg',
    'https://i.postimg.cc/hhdMrLRt/Fish.jpg', 
    'https://i.postimg.cc/Ty1JWmcG/Flowers.jpg'];


const display = () => {
    const picsClone = pics.slice(); // To avoid removing image URLs from the `pics` array
    for (let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        imgs[i].src = picsClone.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * picsClone.length), 1);
    }
};

button.onclick = display;
```

```html
<button id="button">Roll the dice</button>
<img id="dice1"/>
<img id="dice2"/>
<img id="dice3"/>
<img id="dice4"/>
<img id="dice5"/>
<img id="dice6"/>
```

Comment: Fantastic! :D It works! Thank you very much, you solved my problem! :)

Comment: You're welcome :) Also, feel free to mark my answer as approved ;)

Comment: Sure! :) thx, your explanation is very useful, I thought that ' i > arr.lenth' means = stop looping until 'i' is greater than an array :P

Answer (score 1):

Numeric-indexed `id`s in a document are usually a bad idea; consider using classes instead. Also, rather than a `for` loop (which requires manual iteration, and doesn't have any abstraction), consider using `forEach` instead:

```
const dice = document.querySelectorAll('.dice');
button.onclick = () => {
  dice.forEach((die) => {
    die.src = pics[Math.floor(Math.random() * pics.length)]
  });
};
```

```js
const dice = document.querySelectorAll('.dice');
const pics = ['https://i.postimg.cc/MfVDpSmQ/Eagle.jpg',
  'https://i.postimg.cc/QKGQPzZx/Man.jpg',
  'https://i.postimg.cc/1g7MWMzf/Dog.jpg',
  'https://i.postimg.cc/xc9HzM07/Telephone.jpg',
  'https://i.postimg.cc/4mwcbyy3/Robot.jpg',
  'https://i.postimg.cc/ctRRNcd7/Moon.jpg',
  'https://i.postimg.cc/xJW5QCMQ/Dinosaur.jpg',
  'https://i.postimg.cc/hhdMrLRt/Fish.jpg',
  'https://i.postimg.cc/Ty1JWmcG/Flowers.jpg'
];
const button = document.querySelector('#button');
button.onclick = () => {
  dice.forEach((die) => {
    die.src = pics[Math.floor(Math.random() * pics.length)]
  });
};
```

```html
<img class="dice">
<img class="dice">
<img class="dice">
<img class="dice">
<img class="dice">
<img class="dice">
<button id="button">Roll the dice</button>
```

To ensure images aren't repeated, every time the button is clicked, make a copy of the array, then `splice` out the selected item:

```
const [src] = picsCopy.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * picsCopy.length), 1);
die.src = src;
```

```js
const dice = document.querySelectorAll('.dice');
const pics = ['https://i.postimg.cc/MfVDpSmQ/Eagle.jpg',
  'https://i.postimg.cc/QKGQPzZx/Man.jpg',
  'https://i.postimg.cc/1g7MWMzf/Dog.jpg',
  'https://i.postimg.cc/xc9HzM07/Telephone.jpg',
  'https://i.postimg.cc/4mwcbyy3/Robot.jpg',
  'https://i.postimg.cc/ctRRNcd7/Moon.jpg',
  'https://i.postimg.cc/xJW5QCMQ/Dinosaur.jpg',
  'https://i.postimg.cc/hhdMrLRt/Fish.jpg',
  'https://i.postimg.cc/Ty1JWmcG/Flowers.jpg'
];
const button = document.querySelector('#button');
button.onclick = () => {
  const picsCopy = pics.slice();
  dice.forEach((die) => {
    const [src] = picsCopy.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * picsCopy.length), 1);
    die.src = src;
  });
};
```

```html
<img class="dice">
<img class="dice">
<img class="dice">
<img class="dice">
<img class="dice">
<img class="dice">
<button id="button">Roll the dice</button>
```

Comment: Ohhh thx! I was trying with the forEach but I had no clue how to attach it to the button :) Thx! That means a lot to me @CertainPerformance :)

Comment: ! WOOOW! That's amazing! :O I would never come up with this :O How did you learn JS?

Comment: I got interested in fixing site interface problems/data collection through userscripts and wrote a bunch of them while googling anything I didn't know.

Comment: I see, that's amazing! I admire you :D